# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in the Spring security application

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a spring security application where i want every redirect to be secure(https) i have written the below code for that. But it is giving me "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" on the browser. Can anyone please help.

```
http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().hasRole("QA")
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(oidcAuthenticationFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/openid_connect_login")).and().requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you added `.anyRequest().hasRole("QA")` line .This lines  means anyRequest must be authenticated and has role "QA". You should permit at least one page or url.

**Try this**

```
 http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/openid_connect_login/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .anyRequest().hasRole("QA")
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(oidcAuthenticationFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/openid_connect_login")).and().requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
```

Comment: "/openid_connect_login" is my landing page. Can you please me what i should use now?

Comment: please try my changes

Comment: Can you add more detail about your configuration.